# Finding the 'tools' filesystem mounted on /init in WSL2

Tags: mount, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been using linux for a couple of years now, and thought I'd give WSL2 a try.
Something that surprised me was how I could run Windows PE binaries (*.exe files) 'just so'. A bit of research led me to find that this is due to the `binfmt_misc` feature in Linux. I find that the interpreter for windows executables is `/tools/init`.

However, I cannot find the `/tools` directory (All I can find is an executable `/init` file). In WSL2, running `mount | grep tools` gives me this:

```
tools on /init type 9p (ro,relatime,dirsync,aname=tools;fmask=022,loose,access=client,trans=fd,rfd=6,wfd=6)
```

However, I cannot even find `/init/` (The best I could find was `C:\Windows\System32\lxss\tools` in Windows). How does this work in WSL2? Is `/` mounted 'over' these mount points? If so, how can I view the contents of `/tools` or `/init` in WSL2?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, keep in mind that most of WSL is closed-source, so we have to glean some of this from observed-behavior and our understanding of Linux and Windows mechanics.  That said, Microsoft has provided a lot of interesting information on how Interop works.  The Microsoft blog post [Windows and Ubuntu Interopability](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wsl/windows-and-ubuntu-interoperability) is a great read, even if it remains slightly over-my-head, personally.  While it was written in the WSL1 days, most of it is still applicable to WSL2.

Note when reading that blog -- Some of the terminology has changed.  For instance, `bash.exe` is now `wsl.exe`, and "Ubuntu" was the only distribution at the time.

While the Microsoft implementation is closed source, that blog does link to a [precursor open-source project](https://github.com/xilun/cbwin) that allowed WSL to run Windows binaries, so it might be interesting to examine to see what you might learn.

> However, I cannot even find `/init/` (The best I could find was `C:\Windows\System32\lxss\tools` in Windows).

That we can at least answer fairly definitively.  Inside that tools directory in Windows, you will find the `init` binary.  The `/init` that you see inside your WSL (regardless of version 1 or 2) instance does not actually *exist* in the filesystem.  It's mounted by WSL when you star the instance.  Your Windows `C:\Windows\System32\lxss\tools\init` becomes `/init`.

Note that if you are using the WSL Store Preview, then the actual binary comes from the Store package rather than `..\System32\lxss`.

Also note that the blog post above mentions:

> `/init` is a multi-purpose binary that was written by Microsoft and is shipped as a binary resource contained in `LxssManager.dll`.

That may no longer be the case.  For a while, the file sizes of the WSL1 and WSL2 `/init`'s were slightly different.  At this point, the sizes and timestamps appear to be identical, meaning that Microsoft has probably moved the `/init` fully out of `LxssManager.dll` at this point, at least in the Store Preview version I'm running at the moment.

> Is `/` mounted 'over' these mount points?

I think I've answered that above, but just to be clear, it's the other way around.  `/init` is mounted on startup into `/`.  In WSL2, at least, it uses the 9P protocol filesystem, which is a network filesystem.  9P is also used to mount all of the Windows drives into `/mnt/c`, `/mnt/d` (and so on) by default.

```
tools on /init type 9p (ro,relatime,dirsync,aname=tools;fmask=022,loose,access=client,trans=fd,rfd=6,wfd=6)
```

So read that mount point as something like, "The Windows `..\lxss\tools` directory is mounted via the 9P protocol as `/init`."

[More great info](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/uqqmwo/comment/i8z6ngv/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) that I didn't know yet from u/diddlesnaps on your post of the same question on Reddit.  According to that info, which makes perfect sense to me, the `tools` mount is done via the WSL `initrd` and then unmounted.

Comment: "the `tools` mount is .... and then unmounted" -- I am not sure that this is the case. It still is mounted. I believe that the rootfs is mounted 'over' this and then we `pivot_root`

Comment: Moreover, I believe that the architecture of WSL2 shows a fundamental difference, when compared to WSL1. WSL2 is a proper VM (with a proper full linux kernel + hypervisor). WSL1 uses some sort of syscall translation

Comment: The `/init` that you see inside your WSL (regardless of version 1 or 2) instance does not actually exist in the filesystem. It's mounted by WSL when you star the instance" -- In my WSL, `/init` is a binary file. How is it 'mounted' (Typically, directories are 'mounted')? Afaik, it requires a parent/ancestor directory containing /init to be mounted first

Comment: @SuraajKS - (1) *"then we `pivot_root`"* -- You may be right.  I'll noodle on that.  (2)*"architecture of WSL2 shows a fundamental difference"* -- Absolutely.  Nowhere did I say otherwise.  They are quite different, but they do share a similar init process, even though the injection method for init is likely different between the two.  The binary is definitely now the same.  (3) *"`/init` is a binary file. How is it 'mounted'"* -- I think the Reddit answer that I linked is the answer to that, but I'm willing to consider your `pivot_root` suggestion as well.